# Free private repository readers?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository, private

Is it an option to show private repo to others for free (without elevating the license) ? E.g assigning them only the reader role.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible according to the official documentation:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops&tabs=stakeholder